# Checking out remote branch from my github

Tags: git, codeigniter, github

So one of my co-workers did a big upgrade to our framework and pushed the branch up to github for testing. I went to check it out `git checkout <name of remote branch>` (I am on git version 1.8+) and it gives me the following error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        application/controllers/Dashboard.php
        application/controllers/Migrate.php
        application/controllers/Welcome.php
        application/controllers/anon/Anon.php
        application/controllers/cancellationtracker/Cancellationtracker.php
        etc etc
```

So this is a Codeigniter upgrade from 2.2 to 3 and part of the upgrade is Uppercase filenames for controllers. So these files that would be "overwritten" are located in the REMOTE branch not my local branch. I have tried doing `git rm --cached <filename>` on these mysterious files but they don't exist.

All I want to do is checkout his pushed branch so i can test it before merging it into develop. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried multiple stack overflow suggestion. `git clean -f -d` and `git rest --hard origin/develop`. Without a doubt my current branch exactly reflects the remote "develop" branch. However I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You haven't committed your local changes, have you?

Comment: i have completely reset and cleaned the branch im sitting on.....i wish it was as easy as that :(. Weird thing is, normally when I get this error its because of cached changes to files i worked on in the branch im on. The files mentioned in the error are only on the REMOTE branch....so i am clueless

Comment: Don't worry, mate, we will fix ya up. Hard reset to HEAD won't do anything, have you tried to hard reset to remote branch? ```git reset --hard origin/master```

Comment: yup I have done that as well although for me it was origin/develop

Comment: wow I finally figured it out `git config core.ignorecase true`. This fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to a case change on the filename.

`git config core.ignorecase true` fixed it

Comment: if someone wants to put up a detailed explanation as to why this is the case I will make that the answer.

Comment: It is explained in the documentation https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html